# A specific Model of ZFC

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, modal-logic

In his paper "[Some Second Order Set Theory](http://jdh.hamkins.org/somesecondordersettheory/)", Joel Hamkins asked whether there is a model of set theory $V$ that is elementary equivalent to $V[G]$, Whenever $G$ is $V$-generic for the collapse of a cardinal $\delta$ to $\omega$?
It seems that the existence of such a model will have large cardinal strength.
Assume such model exists, then ;

> *1.There is no switches(a statement $\phi$ in language of set theory such that both $\phi$ and $\neg \phi$ can be forced by set forcing-here by collapse forcing)for collapse forcing over this model.*
>
> *2. $\diamondsuit\phi \longleftrightarrow \phi \longleftrightarrow\square \phi$(By collapse forcing).*
>
> *3. $V \models$ MP(Hamkins' maximality principle)*

Assume such a model exists, my questions are :

> **Question 1.** What is valid principle for collapse forcing? Is it modal logic of provability?
>
> **Question 2.** What are other straightforward consequences?
>
> **Question 3.** In general, is this model strange? Is it ugly or no, it's nice? will we have nice consequences or not(not necessarily related to modal logic of forcing)?
>
> **Question 4.** Can this question be asked about other forcing notions, I mean are they interesting?

Comment: I realize that this is quite a technical question which a non-specialist like me cannot answer anyway. But still it would be nice if I could at least understand what is asked. Could you please be just slightly less cryptic?

Comment: @ მამუკა ჯიბლაძე which part?what do you mean by  cryptic?

Comment: It is difficult - for me at least - to figure out exactly what you are asking. For example, your question 1 makes no sense to me - what does "valid principle for collapse forcing" mean?

Comment: I think there's probably a good question here, but for now I've voted to close as "unclear" - I'll retract my close vote, or vote to reopen, if this is fixed.

Comment: I find the question to be clear enough, if one has some familiarity with the modal logic of forcing. I'll write up an answer soon.

Comment: I posted an answer, trying to include some general background that might also help to make the question more understandable.

Comment: @Joel Hamkins, Thank you for answer and clarifying my question, I mean collapse to $\omega$ forcing by collapse forcing, in the case where Γ consists of all collapse-to-ω forcing what is  provably valid modal principles, assuming such a model exists.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins what is $Force^{V}(\mathbb{R})$, for this kind of $V$?could it answer some questions of your paper, the modal logic of forcing?

Comment: Allowing real parameters could throw a wrench into things, as it does in the case where $\Gamma$ is all forcing. $\text{MP}(\mathbb{R})$ has stronger consistency strength than mere MP. But I'm not actually sure it changes things over a model with no switches.

Answer (score 12):

> In a joint work with Mitchell, which is under preparation, we succeeded to give a full answer to Hamkins-Löwe question.

---

**Edit:**

The paper is ready. See

[On a Question of Hamkins and Löwe on the modal logic of collapse forcing](http://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02633).

The proof uses Radin forcing with interleaved collapses. Also it is shown (by Mitchell) that some large cardinals are needed to obtain a consistent answer.

Answer (score 10):

$\newcommand\possible{\diamondsuit}\newcommand\necessary{\square}$The
forcing modalities defined for a given definable class $\Gamma$ of
forcing notions are

- $\varphi$ is $\Gamma$-possible, written $\possible\varphi$, if $\varphi$
  holds in *some* forcing extension by forcing in $\Gamma$.
- $\varphi$ is
  $\Gamma$-necessary, written $\necessary\varphi$, if $\varphi$ holds in *all* forcing
  extensions by a forcing notion in $\Gamma$.

The main question is, for a given class $\Gamma$ of forcing
notions, what are the modal validities of $\Gamma$ forcing? For
example, which modal assertions are correct for c.c.c.-forcing?
for collapse forcing? For proper forcing? And so on. To give an easy example that may illustrate the point: when $\Gamma$ is closed under finite iterations, then $\necessary\varphi\to \necessary\necessary\varphi$ is valid for $\Gamma$-forcing.

I introduced these forcing modalities in [A simple
maximality principle](http://jdh.hamkins.org/maximalityprinciple/), because the maximality principle itself is easily expressed in
this modal language as the assertion that every possibly necessary
statement is true. Benedikt
Löwe and I proved in [The modal logic of forcing](http://jdh.hamkins.org/themodallogicofforcing/) that the ZFC-provably
valid principles of forcing, for the case where $\Gamma$ has all
forcing notions, is precisely the modal logic S4.2. That work made
use of the concepts of buttons and switches:

- $\varphi$ is a *switch*, if $\varphi$ is necessarily possible
  and also $\neg\varphi$ is necessarily possible. In other words,
  you can turn $\varphi$ on and off by further $\Gamma$ forcing. $$\necessary\possible\varphi\qquad\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\qquad\necessary\possible\neg\varphi$$
- $\varphi$ is a *button*, if $\varphi$ is necessary possibly necessary. In
  other words, you can force $\varphi$ in such a way that it remains
  true after any further forcing. $$\necessary\possible\necessary\varphi$$

Our more recent work is [Structural connections between a forcing class and its modal logic](http://jdh.hamkins.org/a-forcing-class-and-its-modal-logic/), joint with George Leibman, expands
on the general connection between the structure of the forcing
notions in a definable class $\Gamma$ of forcing notions and the
modal logic of forcing to which it gives rise. In order to do
this, we introduce a number of other types of modular control
statements, including ratchets, weak buttons and others.

For the case of collapse forcing, we establish in the paper the
following (thm 24), and this answers your question 1:

**Theorem.** (Hamkins, Leibman, Löwe) If ZFC is consistent, then the ZFC provably valid
modal principles of collapse forcing are precisely the assertions
of the modal logic S4.3.

This doesn't mean, however, that every model of ZFC has S4.3 as
its validities. For an upper bound on most of the modal logics, we
had proved in the paper that if a class $\Gamma$ of forcing
notions necessarily has a family of independent switches, then the
modal logic of $\Gamma$-forcing is contained in the modal logic
S5. And what Benedikt and I had noticed earlier was that for
almost all the natural definable classes of forcing $\Gamma$, we
were able to identify families of independent switches. For
example, with c.c.c. forcing, we can always make the continuum
equal to $\aleph_\alpha$ for very specific $\alpha$, either even
or odd (or to have some particular binary bit pattern), and so for
any class $\Gamma$ containing the forcing to do this, there will
be independent switches. In particular, there will always be
forcing extensions $V\subset V[G]$ having different theories. And
we had similar switches for most of the standard classes of
forcing.

But in the case where $\Gamma$ consists of all
collapse-to-$\omega$ forcing, we couldn't seem to identify any
natural switches. Thus, we wondered whether there necessarily were
switches. An extreme negative case of this would be a forcing
extension $V\subset V[G]$ where $V\equiv V[G]$ are elementary
equivalent. And so we had asked whether this was possible.

At the Będlewo set theory meeting in 2007, I mentioned the problem to Paul Larson, who proposed an approach by which we should add a club to a suitable large cardinal and then collapse cardinals between members of the club. At Będlewo, we mentioned the idea to Bill Mitchell, who later carried out such an idea with his proposed solution, [On a
question of Hamkins and Löwe](http://people.clas.ufl.edu/wjm/files/hamkinquestion.pdf), but afterwards backed off of the proposal. (Meanwhile, see Mohammad Golshani's answer for later news on this approach.)

So to summarize the answers to the four questions:

Question 1 is answered in full by the theorem stated above. The provable validities of collapse forcing are precisely S4.3, and this is different from provability logic.

For question 2, if you mean consequences of the situation where necessarily $V\equiv V[G]$ in every collapse extension, then the modal logic trivializes, since if $\possible\varphi\iff\necessary\varphi\iff\varphi$, then all the modal logic in effect evaporates.

For question 3, I'm not sure about the nature of the model apart from the lack of switches, which I find fairly strange. It is a very different situation than occurs with most other classes of forcing, since with other kinds of forcing we can generally affect the theory of the resulting model.

For question 4, we point out in the "Structural connections" paper that all the other natural classes of forcing do not have this situation. Indeed, it was our inability to provide switches in the class of collapse forcing that led to the question. For example, it is a good exercise in forcing to show that there are switches for c.c.c. forcing, or for countably closed forcing, etc. Give it a try!

Comment: Dear Prof. Hamkins, I went through Mitchell's argument and presented a proof of his claim by essentially the same ideas as him, but with some substantial changes in his forcing argument. It is submitted now (with Mitchell's permission), and if the proof be accepted, then we will have a weak answer to your question.

Comment: May I ask you what is the modal logic of collapse forcing in such a model? It seems that it should be very wide, as in such a model we have $\phi \equiv \Diamond \phi \equiv \Box \phi.$

Comment: Thanks a lot, excellent explanation! Just one thing remains unclear for me (well, four things in fact) - do you thus leave all four OP questions open? :)

Comment: Does this mean that modal principles of collapse forcing valid in a particular model of ZFC form a (quasinormal, hence normal) *extension* of S4.3? These have a fairly simple structure. Anyway, there is only one consistent modal logic including the schema $\phi\leftrightarrow\Box\phi$, namely the logic Triv axiomatized by this schema over K.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek In general, the modal principles for collapse forcing over a particular model must contain all the assertions in S4.3, and there are particular models where it is exactly S4.3. If our question is affirmative, it can go all the way up to Triv. But we do not know in general that it must be normal, and so I am interested in your remarks! What is quasinormal? In the case of all forcing, we have examples of models with S4.2 and with S5, but nothing else, and it is an open question whether the modal forcing validities of a fixed model must be normal.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I have edited to make the answers explicit. Basically all four questions are answered.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani That sounds great! Is your paper available? I couldn't find it on the arxiv. I would suggest that you post an answer explaining the argument.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: A quasinormal modal logic is an extension of K closed under substitution and modus ponens. If I understand it correctly, the logic here is quasinormal, right? Now, it is a nontrivial theorem due to Segerberg that all quasinormal extensions of S4.3 are in fact normal (closed under necessitation). See e.g. Theorem 9.55 in Chagrov and Zakharyaschev.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins What I have proved is exactly what is claimed in Mitchell's paper, but the proof is somehow different, as it is claimed in your paper cited in the question, Mitchell's argument does not seem to work. I am not sure my proof be true, and it is not on Arxiv or in my homepage. I will email it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, the modal logic of forcing for any class $\Gamma$ over any fixed model will be quasinormal. And so the Segerberg result gives normality, when one is above S4.3. That is interesting, but it would be more interesting if one could make progress on the case of all forcing, where we can prove the logic is trapped between S4.2 and S5, and both of these endpoints are realized, but we have no other known examples, and do not know whether it is normal.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins thank you for the answers.

Comment: I edited to explain the contribution of Paul Larson at Bedlewo in 2007.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins thank you for your nice edit.